# Setting focus to textbox upon method-execution

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have 2 different commands called; whom each perform some actions and reveal a form. I want them to set focus to the first textbox in that form when they set the `Visible` property to `true`.

I've seen all kinds of SO-articles on this subject, but I just can't seem to puzzle the pieces together. I'm working with MVVM, but all MVVM-solutions look pretty extensive for something that is just a QoL-improvement. I do have *some* code in my codebehind file, so I assumed I could just put it there and have a quicker/cleaner solution, but those I could mostly find for start-up focus.

I've messed around with the Focusmanager, but that doesn't seem to bring me anywhere either.

The tricky part of the whole construction is the following;

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" ItemsSource="{Binding DisabledConfigs}" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedConfig}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectionChanged}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding EditConfig}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>
```

The *EditConfig*-Command triggers a method that checks some properties of the double-clicked object, and either shows a form or not. When it does, the first textbox in that form should receive focus, otherwise nothing of importance happens.

I've been struggling with this stupid QoL-issue for my entire morning now, so I'm prepared to donate my left-kidney to whomever points me in a direction I can cleanly adopt ..

**Edit:** After a suggestion by AdminSoftDK I tried the following

```
// Auto-generated
private void nameBoxEdit_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (nameBoxEdit.IsVisible)
    {
        // nameBoxEdit is (quite self-explanatory) the textbox that I want to focus on
        nameBoxEdit.Focus();
    }
}
```

I'm convinced this should be pretty close to the solution, but it's not working as is.

Comment: Why doesn't the solution "focus the first UI element by tab order on displaying the window" suit your needs?

Comment: @dymanoid because it's not a window that's displayed but a groupbox that has it's `Visible`-property set to false. Only when it's set to true (by doubleclicking another UI element) it shows and should receive focus.

Comment: Put focus controlling logic into View (*dirty* MVVM). ViewModel can provide all necessary: event, it focus can be changed by command, properties, if you need to abstract from which control should get focus, etc.

Comment: I've already tried things like having a `FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding focusedElement}"` set in my `UserControl`, but that didn't seem to make a difference either.

Comment: If you set IsVisibleChanged on both TextBoxes and then set them to Focus as they change to Visible. That is very simple and should work.

Comment: @adminSoftDK that is indeed something I haven't thought of yet.. Let me try that..

Comment: @adminSoftDK I've edited in my attempt at what you meant. I've set the `Focusable`-property in the view on true as well, but to no avail.. Anything I'm missing?

Comment: I've had quite few issues with focus, if this does not work. Then I know couple of other approaches. Try to change this nameBoxEdit.Focus(); to this nameBoxEdit.SelectAll();

Comment: @adminSoftDK Tried `SelectAll()` and `Select(0, 0)` while I was at it, both yield no result. I'm assuming the nameBoxEdit takes inherits the IsVisible property from the groupbox? (it's placed within a grid within the groupbox which' visibility is set)

Comment: The fact that it is inside GroupBox should not make any difference.  Another way to try is kind of hacky, but i got it to work few times like this. Make your private void nameBoxEdit_IsVisibleChanged like this private async void nameBoxEdit_IsVisibleChanged and then try this  if (nameBoxEdit.IsVisible)
        {
            await Task.Delay(500);
            nameBoxEdit.Focus();
        } , I'm not 100% why it works sometimes, but other times in my case it was due to animation taking some time. Some times making it await even 10 works

Comment: @adminSoftDK that combined with `.UpdateLayout()` somehow got it to work. Made a complete run-down in the answer. Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Huge shoutout to adminSoftDK for helping me out here

So I finally got the solution, which looks pretty weird to me, but it's working so I'm not complaining;

```
private void nameBoxAdd_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(!nameBoxAdd.IsVisible)
        {
            nameBoxAdd.UpdateLayout();
            // Task.Delay(500); abundant
            nameBoxAdd.Focus(); 
            // After testing some more, the Task.Delay(500) is not needed either. 
            // It's just the combination of UpdateLayout() and Focus()
        }
    }
```

I had quite an exstensive list of method-calls and property-checks in here to see if anything worked, an low and behold the focus was granted. I started filtering down, and for some reason the combined effort of `UpdateLatyout()` and the delayed task on `Focus()` made it work. Not either on of them (I tried having **just** one or the other which both put me on non-focus again), but the both of them.

Another weird thing to notice is that the `IsVisibleChanged` event triggers **before** actually changing the property. Something I ran across with the debugger..